# How to use a preprocessor variable within a preprocessor function with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I try to run a PowerShell script using `Exec()` preprocessor function, but I need to pass two arguments to it. How can I do that? The following snippet doesn't work.

```
#define PSScript  SourcePath + "\\UpdateJson.ps1"
#define ConfigPath  SourcePath + "\\ClientConfig.json"
#expr Exec("PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File {#PSScript} {#ConfigPath} Str({#BuildNumber})")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` operator, the same way you are already using it in your `PSScript` and `ConfigPath` declarations.

Additionally, the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec) needs the arguments separately.

*Other things:

1) You should wrap the paths to double-quotes, in case they contain spaces.

2) By default, Inno Setup preprocessor does not need escaping of backslashes.*

```
#define PSScript  SourcePath + "\UpdateJson.ps1"
#define ConfigPath  SourcePath + "\ClientConfig.json"

#expr Exec("PowerShell", \
           "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """ + PSScript + """ " + \
               """" + ConfigPath + """ " + Str(BuildNumber))
```